# How to tell when HTTPWebResponse has returned final page?

Tags: c#, .net

I am using HTTPWebResponse to get a web page from a site that has an intermediate screen before the final screen.

Is there a way I can tell when the 2nd (final) page has been rendered so I can screen scrape it?  (the data is in the public domain)

Comment: What do you mean by "an intermediate screen"?  `HTTPWebResponse` is going to give you the response for the request, that's it.  I wouldn't expect it to follow redirects, and I _definitely_ wouldn't expect it to execute any JavaScript that's doing anything on the "intermediate screen."  What is the response you're getting, and what do you need to do with that response?  (Such as parse it for useful information about a redirect and initiate another request.)

Comment: Yes David is right,If you want to scrape anything and if there is any redirection on that page,you need to call that redirection string in HTTPWebResponce,And If that page is protected with CAPTCHA or JAVASCRIPT,You can not Screen Scrape it.

Comment: I'm getting a response that says it's gathering the information, then after about 2 or 3 seconds, it displays the information on subsequent page.

Comment: David:  please form your "comment" as an answer so I may mark this as "answered"  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David May gave the correct answer above.  I am marking this answered, giving him full credit.  Thank you, David.